# Convert Collection to Map

Tags: java, java-7, guava

I have two collections like below:

```
Set<String> attributes = Sets.newHashSet("aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "ddd");
Set<String> activeAttributes = Sets.newHashSet("eee", "lll", "ccc", "mmm");
```

The idea to convert these collections to a map, given that `attributes` collection should be used as keys of this map and `activeAttributes` should be used during calculating value (In case `activeAttributes` contains value from collection `attributes` then "true", otherwise "false" parameter should be set):

As example:

```
({aaa -> false, bbb -> false, ccc -> true, ddd -> false })
```

I've tried to create a Guava function that converts list to collection of Map.Entry:

```
private static class ActiveAttributesFunction implements Function<String, Map.Entry<String, Boolean>> {

    private Set<String> activeAttributes;

    public ActiveAttributesFunction (Set<String> activeAttributes) {
        this.activeAttributes = activeAttributes;
    }

    @Override
    public Map.Entry<String, Boolean> apply(String input) {
        return Maps.immutableEntry(input, activeAttributes.contains(input));
    }
}
```

But, this function will require to convert this list of entries to map.

Please suggest in which way this can be simplified?

Comment: you don't want to use a standard "for" loop ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using Java 8, you can do the following:

```
Set<String> attributes = Sets.newHashSet("aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "ddd");
Set<String> activeAttributes = Sets.newHashSet("eee", "lll", "ccc", "mmm");
Map<String, Boolean> map = attributes.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(s -> s, activeAttributes::contains));
System.out.println(map);
```

For an earlier version of Java and with Guava, you can use [`Maps.asMap`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Maps.html#asMap%28java.util.Set,%20com.google.common.base.Function%29) since Guava 14.0:

```
Map<String, Boolean> map = Maps.asMap(
    attributes, Functions.forPredicate(Predicates.in(activeAttributes)));
```

Note that this returns a live copy (any changes to the set will be reflected on the map). If you want an immutable Map, use [`Maps.toMap`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Maps.html#toMap%28java.lang.Iterable,%20com.google.common.base.Function%29).

Comment: Tunaki: Thanks for answer, but unfortunately we are using java 7. Will update tags.

Comment: Thanks you very much!

Comment: You could replace `s -> activeAttributes.contains(s)` with `activeAttributes::contains`. You could also replace `s -> s` with `Function.identity()` though that's not so neat.